# yaml-cpp: Is it possible to use Merge Key Language-Independent Type?

Tags: yaml-cpp

Yaml spec 1.1 has [Merge Key Language-Independent Type](https://yaml.org/type/merge.html)

Is it possible to parse this merge key from yaml-cpp?